# AS3 showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY) not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I am trying to call 
    Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);

from some action script in Flex. It works on 2 PCs I am testing on, but not on others.  What could be causing this?

On the same PCs it doesn't work on, I get no prompt to allow/deny my camera when I do:

```
var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
```

My local video appears to be white in this case.  These PCs have working web cams, but the prompt never appears.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could it be the PCs where it doesn't work are running a different version of the Flash Player than the ones where it does work?

Comment: The flash versions are the same. I have 2 PCs (one Windows, one Ubuntu) that it does work on, and 2 other (windows, ubuntu) that it doesn't work on. It's so annoying

Comment: Which browsers are you testing with? Note that Chrome and IE have their own Flash plugins. I'm suspecting Chrome's pepper flash might be a problem... Also, make sure that other software (Skype, etc) is not grabbing the cam before Flash.

Comment: Testing with firefox on linux. Firefox and IE on windows. Will double check that no other apps have the camera. But the weird thing is I can query the camera/mic name etc with action script, but just not get the prompt to show.

Comment: I had something like this happen - the security panel would show up but not all the panes were displayed.  It was a while back and only happened on one system, with one browser working and another not working.  I *think* I had to reinstall the browser to get it to work; either that, or remove and reinstall Flash Player.  (Sorry, like I said it was a long time ago and only once...)

Comment: OK thanks. The PCs on which this doesn't work are identical to the ones on which it does - same age / OS install etc.  This is really annoying :-/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible a user was previously prompted to allow access to the camera or microphone and clicked always deny. You can change this by going to the [Global Security Settings pane](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html#117502) and clearing the blocked privilege by clicking **always ask**.

Comment: I did try this, but no luck :'( I don't know if this is related either, but in the right-click menu on the PCs on which this isn't working, I get no "Settings" option (it is disabled).  What might cause this?

Comment: Its most likely that the account does not have adequate permissions. Do the Windows accounts have administrative privleges?

Comment: That's interesting, I'm not sure. I'll double check and let you know.